# How much memory allocation we get for one CosmosDB partitioning within one collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working on partitioning within the cosmosdb collection. Now I know we can have multiple partitions within the same collection as per the picture below

[image]

Now what if my Houston city partitioning need more headspace and how cosmos db will move it within the same collection? Now my guess on this is it will keep it within the same collection and it is not over concern how and where cosmosdb will keep it. But what if over collection is already full and and our Houston city partitioning need more head space? Is CosmosDB going to create new collection and move Houstan there or what and how is it going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atul -

When you create a collection, you choose fixed or unlimited. For fixed you have a fixed size. No confusion there. For an unlimited, you literally have unlimited storage. However, for a particular partition key, the max is 10 GB today. So, not to hit this limit you need to design your partition key in a different manner. In simpler world,  don't have a partition key which will hit the 10 GB limit.

However, to be clear, there is no limit to which your data can grow. You can have multiple partition keys sharing a partition and when it reaches to max it is split into different partitions.

Hope this help. Read more here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data
https://medium.com/@govindk/howto-leverage-azure-cosmosdb-metrics-to-find-issues-and-fix-them-d66d13603bb4

Comment: Hi Rafat can you elaborate a little bit on split in partition? eg if got one partition on city key if it goes beyound 10 gb how is it going to get split by azure? is it going to create 2 partition with same key or 2 different partition? Is it going to keep both partition in same collection(if collection is fix sized)? i guess it will keep the splitted partition in same collection when collection size is unlimited? Thanks once again

Comment: if your partition key is city and as long as you don't have 10 GB of data on ONE city, it will be partitioned automatically. You don't have to do anything. 

If your partition key is city, and you have 10000 city names it may be kept in one partition or different partitions as the cosmos DB see fit (that may be a function of storage and throughput you asked for). Partitions are always belong to a collection. 

Simple mental model to have a partition key for which you can have tens of thousands of values, and don't worry about partitioning.

Comment: so if I select partition key which can have tens of thousands record I can forgot about partitioning but then I won't be able to run transation as transaction is scoped to one partition only. isn't it?

Comment: Though I am stil confused but I accept ur reply as an answer for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Partition management in Cosmos DB is automatic - that is if your partition exceeds its space we will double it. Keep in mind that it is better for query performance to have proper partition key (which should probably not contain just 1 component like in this case) that allows for even distribution than simply rely on Cosmos DB to grow your partitions.